# Using a Linest Function within a Nested Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with VBA and I'm very much a novice.  I basically have 3 columns of data which act as the independent variable (MSCI Value, Growth and Small Cap) and then a blank column followed by numerous columns containing fund data (dependent variables).  Most of these have the same number of rows but a few do not.

I am looking to use the Linest Function in excel to produce the coefficient (beta) of each fund with each independant variable separately (MSCI growth, Value, Small cap).  I am unsure what is the best way to set out my data and vba. And thoughts/ ideas would be much appreciated.

Currently my thoughts are a nested loop.  Whereby I use the Linest function to regress the first independent variable (MSCI Growth, column 2) against the first dependent variable (column 6) and this column number in the range is incremented each time until the column is blank (there are no more funds), and when this happens it loops back to the first fund but changes to the next independent variable (MSCI Value, column 3).  This process is repeated until the last independent variable (MSCI Growth, column 4) is regressed against the last fund.

My problem so far has been 1) creating a Linest Function using named ranges 
2) creating a table where the results of the loop are placed.

```
Set StartCell = Range("B9")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set gRange = Range(StartCell, Cells(LastRow, 2)) 'MSCI growth range

Range("M21").value = Evaluate("Linest(gRange,G9:G112)") 'column G contains the first fund.
```

This code doesn't run, I think it has something to do with the array formula, I only need the coefficient so do not need to run the whole array.

I tried using cell references but when I ran the code I got #VALUE

```
Range("M22").value = Evaluate("Linest(Range((cells(9,2):cells(112,2)),Range(cells(9,7):cells(112,7)))")
```

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way, I want to create a global macro I can use on other sheets but I am unsure how to approach the task.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the vba part from the quotes and concatenate.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("M21").value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("Linest(" & gRange.Address(0,0) & ",G9:G112)")(1)
```

The Second one:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("M22").value = .Evaluate("Linest(" & .Range(.cells(9,2),.cells(112,2)).Address(0,0) & "," & .Range(.cells(9,7),.cells(112,7)).Address(0,0) & ")")(1)
End With
```

This will also error if the two ranges are not the same size.  So make sure they are.